# 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference androidx

Tags: firebase, null, androidx

could you help me, before my code worked well, after the splash I would have my form and I would start the session without any problem, but now I don't know what it was that I got this error ... I already tried several solutions from other forums and no I get to fix it.

it literally tells me what the uid is but I don't know how to make it not null

```
package com.example.medicare;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.example.medicare.modelo.Cita;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import cn.pedant.SweetAlert.SweetAlertDialog;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView nombreC, nss;
    CircleImageView imagenPerfil;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    DatabaseReference dbdReferencia;
    FirebaseUser usuario;
    String uid;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    String pacienteNombreC, pacienteNss, fechaHoy;
    int numeroCitas;
    static int token = 0;
    String[] numeros = {"uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis", "siete", "ocho", "nueve", "diez"};

    public static void setToken(int number)
    {
        token = number;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        numeroCitas = 0;
        sp = getSharedPreferences("Iniciar Sesion", MODE_PRIVATE);
        usuario = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        nombreC = findViewById(R.id.nombreCompleto);
        nss = findViewById(R.id.nss);
        imagenPerfil = findViewById(R.id.imagen_perfil);
        uid = usuario.getUid();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        fechaHoy = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(c.getTime());


        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Citas");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Cita cita = data.getValue(Cita.class);
                    if (cita.getEmailPaciente().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()) &&
                            cita.getestado().equals("Aceptado") &&
                            cita.getfecha().equals(fechaHoy)
                    )
                        numeroCitas++;
                }
                if (numeroCitas == 1) {
                    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(com.example.medicare.MenuActivity.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_heart_beats)
                            .setContentTitle("Cita diaria")
                            .setContentText("Usted tiene una cita el dia de hoy")
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#33AEB6"))
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
                }
                if (numeroCitas > 1) {
                    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(com.example.medicare.MenuActivity.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_heart_beats)
                            .setContentTitle("Citas diarias")
                            .setContentText("Usted tiene " + numeros[numeroCitas - 1] + " citas el dia de hoy")
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#33AEB6"))
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

                }
                if (numeroCitas == 0) {
                    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(com.example.medicare.MenuActivity.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_heart_beats)
                            .setContentTitle("Citas diarias")
                            .setContentText("Usted no tiene citas el dia de hoy")
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#33AEB6"))
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

                }
                if(token == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(com.example.medicare.MenuActivity.this, AsignarCitaActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(com.example.medicare.MenuActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE
                    );
                    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        dbdReferencia = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Pacientes");
        dbdReferencia.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //pacienteNombreC = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("apellidos").getValue(String.class) + " " + dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("nombreC").getValue(String.class);
                pacienteNombreC = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("nombreC").getValue(String.class);
                pacienteNss = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("nss").getValue(String.class);
                nombreC.setText(pacienteNombreC);
                nss.setText(pacienteNss);
                StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
                StorageReference profileRef = storageReference.child("imagen_perfil").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail() + ".jpg");
                profileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Picasso.get().load(uri).into(imagenPerfil);
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void buscarDoctor(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(com.example.medicare.MenuActivity.this, BuscarDoctorEspecialidadActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void Citas(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(com.example.medicare.MenuActivity.this, AsignarCitaActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void perfilInfo(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(com.example.medicare.MenuActivity.this, PerfilPacienteInfo.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void abrirExpedienteMedico(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(com.example.medicare.MenuActivity.this, ExpedienteMedico.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void cerrarSesion(View view) {
        sp.edit().putBoolean("Sesion cerrada", false).apply();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(com.example.medicare.MenuActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        SweetAlertDialog dialog = new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.WARNING_TYPE);
        dialog.setConfirmText("Si");
        dialog.setCancelText("No");
        dialog.setContentText("Estas seguro que deseas salir de edicare ?");
        dialog.setTitleText("Cerrar Aplicacion");
        dialog.setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                finishAffinity();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        dialog.setCancelClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                sweetAlertDialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }

    public void myDoctors(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(com.example.medicare.MenuActivity.this, MisDoctoresActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: is the user logged in? Did you sign `signinwithemailandpassword()`...?

Comment: The user is not logged in, after the splash he goes to login and when he logs in he goes to the activity menu, he still does not have to open the activity menu. But before it did not give me that error, it just opens the splash and it does not redirect me to the beginning of the session because the application closes and throws me that error.

Comment: I just read that uninstalling it and reinstalling it and it actually worked